# Phonegap build pushplugin with iOS

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

I'am very new to phonegap and building apps

Im using the sample code from pushplugin, and the notifications on my android work, but I am not even getting registered on my ipod, in the tokenHandler function it is supposed to log the response in the console and nothing is showing up, it logs fine in the android function.

All that I have done so far that involves push notifications is create the push notification certificate in the apple developer center, and it says that push notifications are enabled for the development version of the app.

For the android notifications I had to do a lot more to get it to work so I feel like Im missing a step

Am I supposed to do something with that certificate? I read somewhere that you are supposed to install the certificate on the server that is going to be sending the messages? If that is true how do I do that? The webserver that will be sending it is an ubuntu command line only server with apache2

And in the pushplugin code I had to enter the senderId for the android side, is there something similar Im supposed to enter in the code on the ios side.

When I first opened the app on my ipod, it said that this app wants to send me push notifications and I said OK, but still i am not getting any register response

Thanks for any help, I was doing so good by myself until I started on the apple app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was because the ondeviceready function was not firing with the ios device, it is with the android, i made a setTimeout function in the onload jquery function to register it a few seconds later and its working great now

Don't know if there is a better way, but Im happy for now